# appending values in list of python

Tags: python

this is my code below

```
mylist = [[32401, 20], [32402,30], [32939, 42], [32940, 10], [32941, 15], [40000, 123], [40100, 234]]

def collect(sublist):
     current =  32400 +((mylist[0] - 32400) // 540) * 540 #atime??
     flag = current + 540
     temp = []
     dPrices = []

     if sublist[0] < flag:
         temp.append(sublist[1])
     else:
         maxValue = max(temp)
         del temp[:]
         dPrices.append((current, maxValue))

     print dPrices


for i in mylist:
    collect(i)
```

then i have nothing(empty list)

but what i want to have is like [32400, 42], [32940, 15], [39960, 234]

what is the problem?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you mean it prints nothing each time `collect` is called? Have you checked the values of `myList[0]` and `flag` for the if statement `if mylist[0] < flag:`?

Comment: There are a few oddities in this code, but in order to be able to tell what is the problem/fault we would need to know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I modified your code a little, for instance you should not shadow the global `mylist` by calling the function parameter likewise. Furthermore, the variable `dPrices` was called `dPrice` in some places.

Answer (score 0):

when you define a funtion in python, you have to end it stating what it has to return as result.

At the end you have to write:
return ...

replacing the dots with the variable or list or whatelse you want the result of the function to be.

Answer (score 0):

With your if statement `mylist[0]` will always be less than `flag`. This is because all the stuff you do at the start basically just says that `current = mylist[0]`. The flag is then `mylist[0] + 540` which will always be bigger than `mylist[0]`. So your program will never go into the else clause of your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should give you roughly what you are looking for:

```
import bisect, operator

mylist = [[32401, 20], [32402,30], [32939, 42], [32940, 10], [32941, 15], [40000, 123], [40100, 234]]
mylist = sorted(mylist)
keys = [entry[0] for entry in mylist]

step_size = 540
block = 32400
lPrices = []
start = 0

while block <= mylist[-1][0]:
    entry = bisect.bisect_left(keys, block+step_size)

    if entry - start:
        lPrices.append((block, max(mylist[start:entry], key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1]))
    start = entry
    block += step_size

print lPrices
```

It produces a list of prices as follows, giving the following output:

```
[(32400, 42), (32940, 15), (39960, 234)]
```

It first makes sure your list is in ascending order. For each block increment, it then uses the `bisect` function to find the location in your list of the highest entry for that block. The highest value in that block is then calculated and added to the `lPrices` list. The block is then advanced until the end of the mylist block range is reached.

Tested in Python 2.7